# How to run Webtests during a TFS Build?

Tags: tfs, automation, visual-studio-2015, webtest

I need to run some WebTests (defined in files with the extension ".webtest") in automated TFS build. I can successfully run these Web Tests locally from Visual Studio 2015 but cannot get them to execute during a Team Build.

In the Team Build Definition, I have tried with the "Test assembly file specification" value = "*.webtest". But this fails to pick up the Web Tests. I can see that the .webtest files have been copied under the "Binaries" directory so I'm a bit puzzled why they are not found.

[Test Specification Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3hxQ.png)

What am I missing? How do you get the .webtest files to run under a Team Build?

Note:

TFS Version: 2013 (Agent has VS2015 installed)

Answer (score 0):

Open the ellipsis in the Test Source field:

[image]

Specify MSTest.exe runner (VS2010 compatible) as the Test Runner and change the Test Assembly file specification to run everything that has an extension of .webtest.

[image]

More details -

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/08/16/build-deploy-web-performance-test-with-tfs-build/

Comment: The Build Template I'm using do not have 'MSTest.exe runner (VS2010 compatible)' as an option under test runner list. It's just have 'Visual Studio Test Runner'. Do you know how to add another test runner to the build template??

Comment: Can you change your process template?

Comment: Yes, I have the permission to do that. I found the part describing the test runner. Can you help me with what I have to do to add MsTest as a test runner?

<Sequence....
 ...
 <mtba:RunAgileTestRunner DisplayName="Run VS Test Runner" Enabled="[AutomationPlatformTests]" TestSpecs="[AutomatedTests]" ConfigurationsToTest="[ConfigurationsToBuild]" />
 ...
</Sequence>

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Test Runner can't run web test and load test. You need to use MSTest.exe to run them in TFS build. You can can add the InvokeProcess activity to run mstest command: `mstest /TestContainer: WebTest1.webtest`